# P5Js modifying local file such as json or xml or table

Tags: javascript, file, processing, p5.js

P5Js allows you write a json/table/xml file on the disk but I couldn't find a way to modify the existing file.

There is way through which you can open a local file[json/table/xml] in P5js and there is another way thought which you can write/create a file on local disk but I couldn't found how to modify a local file or add a new entry in the existing local json or table or xml file.

1. [P5.Js](http://p5js.org/)
2. [P5.Js write a file](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveTable)
3. [P5.Js loadFile](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadTable)
4. [P5.Js Table
   reference](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Table)

I do found some example to this but they are using different technologies 
[Link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-own-to-do-app-with-html5-and-indexeddb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.

If you want to use the browser, you have two options:

1. Use [saveTable()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveTable), [saveJSON()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveJSON), etc. which will download a file. (Press the edit button in the reference snippet, hit run see what I mean)
2. Try [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for small pieces or data, or use a database otherwise (may require a wee bit of server-side scripting)

With option 1 you'd have a loop like this:

1. load the file (file browse dialog or drop the file onto the browser (there's a p5.js example for that))
2. parse and modify the file in p5.js
3. save/download the file from p5.js

Other options may include using a wrapper for your js code into an application. 
As you've mentioned, app.js/electron.js/cordova/etc. will provide options.

It might be worth trying node.js since there already is a [p5.js node.js tutorial](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js,-node.js,-socket.io) out there

Answer (score 1):

You can't. (**Edit:** You can't, unless you do something more complicated like George's answer.)

Think about how scary it would be if JavaScript could modify files on your hard drive. Any time you visited a website, all of the kitten pictures you have might be deleted!

Depending on what you want to do, you might be able to use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Or you might have to create a database and save to that. Or a server. The point is, it's not as simple as modifying a file on the user's computer.

If you really need to modify a file on the user's computer, then you can't use JavaScript. You can use regular Processing in Java mode and deploy as an application, but you can't embed that in a webpage.

Comment: I understand the concern but there must be some workaround. What about appjs or  electroonjs ? What I am basically trying to do is to create a note taking app for windows. Though I dont even know much about appjs or electronjs but I read people are using them to create cross platform application.

Comment: Also other than using web technologies what else can I use to create responsive desktop application?

Comment: @Ryder Like my answer says, you can use Processing in Java mode to deploy as a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous approaches for data persistence exist. Deciding which approach to take depends on your needs. Begin by clarifying what data you need to persist and the scope of data access (single user or all users). Another consideration is complexity, particularly for learners who are new to coding.

For simple use cases, like persisting a user's preferences, or building a per-user high scores table, I'd start with [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). It's simple to use and well-supported. The disadvantage is that it's specific to a single user (although that may be all you need). If the user clears their local browser files, local storage will be cleared.

The API is simple:

```js
// set a key to a value
localStorage.setItem("score", score);

// get the value for a key
const score = localStorage.getItem("score");
```

For more complex data, like an array or object, you can use `JSON.stringify()` and serialize the data structure going into local storage and `JSON.parse()` to restore it after pulling it out.

If you want to use a backend server so you can share data across clients, SQLite is a good starter database, but this is still pretty complex for most beginners since it involves SQL. Avoiding SQL can be done using an object relational mapper (ORM) like Sequelize, but such libraries also tend to have a steep learning curve.

A JSON file is not scalable for serious apps, but should be far more accessible to learners and is a great entry point to backend development. I'll add an example below you can run and modify to meet your needs.

Here's the server.js code, which uses a single library called Express, which makes it easier to develop a server application:

```js
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

const scoresPath = "scores.json";
const scores = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(scoresPath, {encoding: "utf-8"}));
const app = express();
app
  .set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000)

  // serve the sketch HTML and other static assets
  // from the public/ directory, if you want
  .use(express.static("public"))

  // ...or enable requests from other origins if
  // your sketch isn't on the same server
  .use((request, response, next) => {
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
  })

  // a single endpoint that can accept data in the form
  // /scores?name=foo&score=42
  // or returns all scores if no query parameters are provided
  .get("/scores", (request, response) => {
    if (request.query.name && request.query.score) {
      scores[request.query.name] = +request.query.score;
      fs.writeFile(scoresPath, JSON.stringify(scores), (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
    }

    response.json(scores);
  })
  .listen(app.get("port"), () =>
    console.log("listening on port", app.get("port"))
  );
```

and create a scores.json data file with an empty object in it:

```json
{}
```

Here's the p5.js script (public/index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>P5.js client-server persistence example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script>

let scores;
let scoresEl;

function randomString(n=10) {
  let res = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res += String.fromCharCode(floor(random(97, 122)));
  }

  return res;
}

function renderScores() {
  scoresEl.elt.textContent = JSON.stringify(scores, null, 2);
}

function addScore() {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    score: floor(random(0, 100)),
    name: randomString(),
  });
  scores = loadJSON(`scores?${params.toString()}`, renderScores);
}

function setup() {
  scoresEl = createElement("pre", "Loading scores...");
  scoresEl.position(5, 30);
  scores = loadJSON("scores", renderScores);
  const newScoreBtn = createButton("Add new score"); 
  newScoreBtn.position(5, 5);
  newScoreBtn.mousePressed(addScore); 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Install Node on your system and open a terminal, then run

```bash
npm init -y
npm i express@4.18.2
node server
```

With the server running, navigate to http://localhost:5000 to run the client app and click the button to add a few scores. Scores should persist even after cycling the server on and off, and you'll see the scores.json file updating.

I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible, but there's still a lot going on here. Try making adjustments and researching the individual concepts in isolation, like JSON file reading and writing, creating routes in Express, and so on. Adjust the app to work with a simple game of your own creation.

In the interest of keeping things compact, I've avoided most error handling. For complex data, a POST route is preferable to a GET route as I used here, but it's a little bit more complex to implement.

You can run the server locally, or you can code and host the server on a free tier on a hosting site like glitch.me or repl.it, although there may be restrictions, like slow startup time. Always-on server apps usually cost money.

You don't have to use Node.js for the backend, although it's probably the easiest option for those already using JS on the frontend. Hosting on a site like Python Anywhere and developing your code using Python and Flask may be appealing to those who have experience with it.

Firebase is another persistence option to consider.

Keep in mind, p5 is just a rendering library for HTML5, so anything that works for browser JS will work for p5 as well.